# Could not find library corresponding to plugin

Tags: ros, rviz, library, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I'm trying to learn how to write rviz plugins from the book **Mastering Ros for robotics**.But there is a problem  I cannot solve. I created the package and then created the `teleop_pad.h` file here:

```
#ifndef TELEOP_PAD_H
#define TELEOP_PAD_H

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <rviz/panel.h>
class QLineEdit;

namespace rviz_teleop_commander
{
    //所有的plugin都必须是rviz：：panel的子类
    class TeleopPanel: public rviz::Panel
    {
        //后面需要用到Qt的信号和槽，都是Qobject的子类，所以需要声明Q_OBJECT宏
        Q_OBJECT
        public:

        //构造函数。在类中会用到QWidget的实力来实现GUI界面，这里先初始化为0
    TeleopPanel(QWidget* parent =0 );

    //重载rviz::Panel基类中的函数，用于保存、加载配置文件中的数据，在我们这个plugin
   // 中，数据就是topic的名称
   virtual void load(const rviz::Config& config);
   virtual void save(rviz::Config config) const;

   //公共槽
   public Q_SLOTS:
    // 当用户输入topic的命名并按下回车后，回调用此槽来创建一个相应名称的topic publisher
    void setTopic (const QString& topic)

//内部槽
protected Q_SLOTS:
void sendvel();                 // 发布当前的速度值
void update_Linear_Velocity();  // 根据用户的输入更新线速度值
void update_Angular_Velocity(); // 根据用户的输入更新角速度值
void updateTopic();             // 根据用户的输入更新topic name

//内部变量
protected:
//topic names输入框
QLineEdit* output_topic_editor_;
QString output_topic_;

//线速度输入框
 QLineEdit* output_topic_editor_1;
 QString output_topic_1;
 
 //角速度输入框
  QLineEdit* output_topic_editor_2;
 QString output_topic_2;

 //// ROS的publisher，用来发布速度topic
 ros::Publisher velocity_publisher_;

 //ROS node handle
 ros::NodeHandle nh_;
 //当前保存的线速度和角速度
 float linear_velocity_;
 float angular_velocity_;
};
}  //end namespace rviz_plugin_tutorial

#endif //TELEOP_PANEL_H
```

the teleop_pad.cpp file

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>

#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <QDebug>

#include "teleop_pad.h"
namespace rviz_teleop_commander {
//构造函数，初始化变量
TeleopPanel::TeleopPanel(QWidget *parent)
    : rviz::Panel(parent), linear_velocity_(0), angular_velocity_(0) {
  // 创建一个输入topic命名的窗口
  QVBoxLayout *topic_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  topic_layout->addwidget(new QLabel("Teleop Topic"));
  output_topic_editor_ = new QLineEdit;
  topic_layout->addwidget(output_topic_editor_);

  // 创建一个输入线速度的窗口
  topic_layout->addwidget(new QLabel("Linear Velocity"));
  output_topic_editor_1 = new QLineEdit;
  topic_layout->addwidget(output_topic_editor_1);

  //创建一个输入角速度窗口
  topic_layout->addwidget(new QLabel("Angular Velocity"));
  output_topic_editor_2 = new QLineEdit;
  topic_layout->addwidget(output_topic_editor_2);

  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  layout->addLayout(topic_layout);
  setLayout(layout);

  //创建定时器，发布消息
  QTimer *output_timer = new QTimer(this);



 //设置信号与槽连接
  connect(output_topic_editor_, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this,
          SLOT(updateTopic())); //输入topic命名，回车后，调用updateTopic()
  connect(
      output_topic_editor_1, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this,
      SLOT(
          update_Linear_velocity())); //输入线速度值，回车后，调用update_Linear_Velocity()
  connect(
      output_topic_editor_2, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this,
      SLOT(
          update_Angular_velocity())); //输入角速度值，回车后，调用update_Angular_Velocity()

  //设置定时器的回调函数。按周期调用sendvle
  connect(output_timer, SIGNAL(timerout()), this, SLOT(sendVel()));
  output_timer->start(100);
}

//更新线速度
void TeleopPanel::update_Linear_velocity() {
  //获取输入框内的数据
  QString temp_string = output_topic_editor_1->text();
  //将字符串转换为浮点数
  float lin = temp_string.toFloat();
  //保存当前输入值
  linear_velocity_ = lin;
}

void TeleopPanel::update_Angular_velocity {
  QString temp_string = output_topic_editor_2->text();
  float ang = temp_string.toFloat();
  angular_velocity_ = ang;
}

//更新topic命名
void TeleopPanel::setTopic(const QString &new_topic) {
  //检查topic是否改变
  if (new_topic != output_topic_) {
    output_topic_ = new_topic;
    //如果命名空，不发布任何信息
    if (output_topic_ == "") {
      velocity_publisher_.shutdown();
    }
    //否则初始化publisher
    else {


     velocity_publisher_ =
          nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(output_topic_.toStdstring(), 1);
    }
    Q_EMIT configChanged();
  }
}

//发布消息
void TeleopPanel::sendVel() {
  if (ros::ok() && velocity_publisher_) {
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x = linear_velocity_;
    msg.linear.y = 0;
    msg.linear.z = 0;
    msg.angular.x = 0;
    msg.angular.y = 0;
    msg.angular.z = angular_velocity_;
    velocity_publisher_.publish(msg);

  }
}

//重载基类功能
void TeleopPanel::save(rviz::Config config) const {
  rviz::Panel::save(config);
  config.mapSetvalue("Topic", output_topic_);
}

// 重载父类的功能，加载配置数据
void TeleopPanel::load(const rviz::Config &config) {
  rviz::Panel::load(config);
  QString topic;
  if (config.mapGetString("Topic", &topic)) {
    output_topic_editor_->setText(topic);
    updateTopic();
  }
}

} // end namespace rviz_plugin_tutorials

  // 声明此类是一个rviz的插件
  #include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
  PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(rviz_telop_commander::TeleopPanel,rviz::Panel)
  //tutorial
```

the package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>rviz_teleop_commander</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The rviz_teleop_commander package</description>

  <maintainer email="shantengfei@todo.todo">shantengfei</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rviz</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rviz</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
   <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

the plugin_descriptioin.xml

```
<library path="lib/librviz_teleop_commander">
  <class name="rviz_teleop_commander/Teleop"
         type="rviz_teleop_commander::TeleopPanel"
         base_class_type="rviz::Panel">
    <description>
      A panel widget allowing simple diff-drive style robot base control.
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

and the CMakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rviz_teleop_commander)

find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_FILES
  src/teleop_pad.h
)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  src/teleop_pad.cpp 
  ${MOC_FILES}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I can build the package successfully After build it i have source the setup.bash of my workspace. But when I rosrun the rviz and tried to add this new panel, the error came up:

```
[ERROR] [1511090623.201457618]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'rviz_teleop_commander/TeleopPanel' failed to load.  Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin rviz_teleop_commander/TeleopPanel. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
```

I have checked the package.xml and the name in  description.xml just I showed above.but I still couln't find how to solve it.Could anyone help me? Thanks!
Update:I have changed all`telop*`to`teleop*`,but still doesn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276250/could-not-find-library-corresponding-to-plugin/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-19**:\

> The plugin for class 'rviz_teleop_commander/TeleopPanel' failed to load

There are quite some inconsistencies in the various file you show: `rviz_telop_commander/Teleop` vs `rviz_teleop_commander/TeleopPanel` is one.

I would suggest you check all of them.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-19**:
Thanks gvdhoorn.I have changed alltelop*toteleop*,but still doesn't work but it  still doesn't work. I checked several times,but still have no idea where the error is.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-20**:
gvdhoorn,I rebuilt the whole example from the beginning and now it works.Maybe I still didn't find the inconsistencies in the first version.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have rebuilt the example and now it works. I guess I still didn't find the inconsistencies in the first version. now it works.

---

Originally posted by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) with karma: 88 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0